# Android Studio auto imports libraries whenever I try to type before package name

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to write comments in the first line of my java code when suddenly Studio started to auto import libraries while I have already done so.

I have already tried to clean project and then rebuild project, but this behavior persists. I can copy and paste my comments to the first line without triggering auto import. I also cloned some projects for testing, it still happens. What is causing this and how can I fix it?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

By "auto import libraries" I suppose you mean "auto import packages". If thats the case then goto

> File -> Settings -> General -> Auto Import
>
> (for MAC) AndroidStudio -> Preferences  -> General -> Auto Import

Uncheck "Optimize imports on the fly."

[image]

Comment: I have already tried this, it reduces number of packages it imports, but still imported the following: import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;  I have alrady imported these after my package name